# How to perform a Git merge while updating/consolidating the history

Tags: git

To start off with, I'm aware of `--squash` but that doesn't solve my problem on its own.

I have two branches, `A` and `B`, where `A` needs to be merged into `B` periodically. For all intents and purposes these two branches represent separate projects with different teams being responsible for them, but `A` contains common code that acts like a library in `B`. Now, ignoring that this is a simplified example and the answer isn't as easy as "extract the common library code to a new branch/repo `C`, how can I periodically merge `A` into `B` without pulling in all of `A`'s history as well?

The reason we don't want history is because they are effectively two separate projects, and 90%+ of the changes on `A` just won't matter to `B` (from a developer understanding what's going on in the history perspective). To complicate matters a bit more, we'd still like to support a feature branch approach whereby a developer should be able to create a feature branch from `A`, then another feature branch from `B`, and finally merge changes from `A`'s feature branch to `B`'s feature branch.

---

Options that we've considered:

### Regular Merge

Everything works, except we have all of `A`'s history in `B` as well.

### Squash

Squash gets rid of the history, but as we'll continue to merge from `A` to `B` we'll run into conflicts unless we manually keep track of which commits have already been merged. This becomes a problem with the feature branch workflow as each developer will have to craft their merges carefully so as to exclude anything that has been squashed before (or alternatively cherry-pick).

### Subtree (read-tree)

Doesn't support branching nicely as far as we can tell. When the developer creates two feature branches they'll have to somehow update the subtree to point to `A`'s feature branch instead of `A` itself. When merging the feature branch to master the developer will have to revert/correct this subtree pointer again.

### Submodules

Same problem as subtree but with a bunch of others added as well.

---

Any suggestions for how we can achieve the primary goal (frequent merges without complete history)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the constraints you've imposed, there just isn't a good solution.  There is a solution, which I'll outline below; but first I want to be clear - I don't believe it's a *good* solution and I think you probably will end up with problems.[1]

But if for some reason you must try it anyway:

You'll have to create a sort of bridge branch.  This branch will contain an abridged history of `A`.  You'll update it periodically with just the useful information for `B`; then you'll merge that into `B`.

Because you said a simple merge works except that it brings in too much history, I assume that no transformation of the content is necessary - so all you need is a sparse history.  That means that while the history in `B` will be reduced to fewer commits, all the changes are still there in those fewer commits.  If you need to avoid even that, I guess let me know in comments... but the solution gets noticeably more complicated.

Also because a merge would work, I assume there is a common ancestor of branches `A` and `B`, which I'll call `O`.

```
... O -- x -- x -- x -- P <--(A)
     \
      y -- y -- y <--(B)
```

`B` is "up to date" with `O`, but not with any later changes from `A`.  You want changes from `P` reflected in `B`, but you don't want to see the `x` commits in `B`s history.  First we'll create the "bridge branch" at `O`.  We need an expression that resolves to `O` - which could be the commit ID for `O`, but in this example we can use `A~4` (`A` refers to `P`, so we want the 4th parent of `A`).

```
git checkout A~4
git checkout -b bridge
```

Now the question is how you *repeatably* update `bridge`.  As you noted, the first time you could do a

```
git merge --squash
```

but this is not repeatable, because the 2nd time you try it git won't know the correct merge base.  Likewise, the first time you could do an interactive `rebase` and use the TODO list to `squash` all the commits together, but to repeat that you'd have to keep track of how much of `A` had already been copied to `bridge`, and that's error-prone.

But what the bridge branch gives you is a guarantee - the *only* source of changes to `bridge` will be the merges from `A`, so in each "merge" we can assume that all changes are "theirs".  In other words, we always just want to commit, onto `bridge`, a specific state of `A` (probably the current state).

There are a few ways to get that.  Starting from

```
      x -- x -- x -- P <--(A)
     /
... O <--(bridge)
     \
      y -- y -- y <--(B)
```

a porcelain approach would be

```
git checkout --detach A
git reset --soft bridge
git checkout bridge
git commit -m "Update from A through P"
```

Now you have

```
      x -- x -- x -- P <--(A)
     /
... O -- P' <--(bridge)
     \
      y -- y -- y <--(B)
```

so you can

```
git checkout B
git merge bridge
```

to get

```
      x -- x -- x -- P <--(A)
     /
... O ----------- P' <--(bridge)
     \              \
      y -- y -- y -- M1 <--(B)
```

Now you've minimized how much of `A`s history will show up in `B`.  You still see all the changes of course - again, we're modifying the history, but still incorporating all of the content changes.

Now more work happens and you get to a new state, where the common code has been updated again in `A` at commit `Q`.

```
      x -- x -- x -- P -- x -- x -- Q <--(A)
     /
... O ----------- P' <--(bridge)
     \              \
      y -- y -- y -- M1 -- y -- y -- y <--(B)
```

Again you note that `bridge` doesn't take changes from any other source; it still matches `P` so you still just want to update it to match `Q`.  So you repeat the process

```
git checkout --detach A
git reset --soft bridge
git checkout bridge
git commit -m "Update from A through Q"
git checkout B
git merge branch
```

and even though nothing in this process "knew" that `branch` was at `P`, still we end with

```
      x -- x -- x -- P -- x -- x -- Q <--(A)
     /
... O ----------- P' ----------------- Q' <--(bridge)
     \              \                    \
      y -- y -- y -- M1 -- y -- y -- y -- M2 <--(B)
```

And you can repeat this as often as you need.

---

[1] - I'm assuming that just using options like `--first-parent` on the `log` command isn't a suitable solution, as this might also cut out history from topic branches within the `B` project that you want to see.  But you may want to consider whether looking at the problem from that angle simplifies anything...

And, while you've ruled it out, the best solution may well be to pull the common code out to a library and make it a dependency of both projects (and, in the process, I would move the projects to separate repos instead of just separate branches).  That may be "easier said than done", but if so that probably points to an architecture problem that's going to cause you other headaches anyway if left unsolved.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's a very impressive answer. I though of a "bridge" branch as well but couldn't quite get it to work. I wasn't explicit on the feature branches though and I fear the next requirement will break the camel's back. The feature branches are merged back to A and B at some stage, so you could have changes of A (coming from the feature branch) end up in B (feature branch again) before the squashed bridge commit is made. If I understand everything you wrote correctly, this should conflict? PS. why the need for a detached checkout? Won't the subsequent reset and checkout work the same?

Comment: @Zecrates : Last question first:  If you have a branch checked out, `reset` moves the branch ref.  The `detached` checkout prevents the `A` branch ref from moving.  Re-reading what you said about the feature branches - yes, those are going to be a problem.  If the bridge isn't the *only* way for changes to flow from `A` to `B`, then not only the feature branch itself, but also `A` history that exists when the feature branch is created, will "leak" into `B` in potentially-conflicting ways.  I warned you there'd be problems; you just hit them faster than I thought.

Comment: Thanks. Clearly no perfect solution for our case, we might just have to live with the additional history. We'll see whether we can't write our own tool/script to exclude commits coming from certain parents in git log.